# SQL View for many DBs (and growing) on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, multi-tenant, sql-view

In a multi-tenanted SaaS I'm looking at data isolation and the benefits of a single DB vs DB per tenant on SQL server using Azure. The software I am using there MUST be a central DB (this can be the single DB). Web services look at this central DB to push data to mobile users. If using DB per tenant all the tenant DBs must be linked to the central DB - a linked SQL View?

Reading up on views, they do not necessary slow down queries if indexed correctly but, my question is what are the limitations of using an SQL view for many databases? If I start with 5 customers (5 DBs) and in a year end up with 100 DBs will it become too unwieldy/unresponsive?

Users will be live querying data so the response time needs to be as quick as possible.

Is there a better way instead of using a view?

Comment: you mean all tenant dbs be part of a server ?? of course yes. again you can have a multiple server option too. but using a same db with partitioning for every tenant is how maximize resource utilization.

Comment: all tenants DBs will reside on the same SQL server instance. My question is how to link the tenant DBs to the the central DB so that the web service will look at the all data/tenant-dbs as one central DB?

My concern with utilizing 1 single db for all tenants is data isolation, and backup/recovery. If a customer finds they need to revert to old data for whatever reason (even though this scenario is doubtful) it could still be achieved by having DB-per-tenant

Comment: Individual database for tenants is a simple and safe approach. Each tenant will have a configuration or profile in which dB connection string will be a property and you'll use that to connect to the right dB. In case of shared dB one can always achieve logical isolation. Sharding, partitioning, federations etc help to get that. Backup and recovery for partitions, shardlets are available. You can explore them.